# Big Bang and Spherical Symmetry

Tags: symmetry, universe, big-bang

If the universe did indeed start with the big bang why is the universe not spherically symmetric?

As per [Wikipedia entry on Big Bang](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Big_Bang&oldid=576832487), (and my understanding as well) big bang is the best explanation as of now.

> The Big Bang is the scientific theory that is most consistent with
>   observations of the past and present states of the universe, and it is
>   widely accepted within the scientific community.

Basically considering the universe as a sphere (all points equidistant from a center) for any given state at any given point, there should have existed an identical state at the other end (line passing through the center) of the sphere. Also, all points equidistant from the center should have had the same 'state'.

What is the explanation for the 'asymmetry' that we have today?

Comment: Asymmetry as in ? As I see, if you cannot find the centre of universe how can you comment on its symmetry ?

Comment: Since the big bang has a starting point, I consider that to be the center.

Comment: @ Ravindra HV : Some theories say that it might have started as if it has started from a centre, those theories contradict big bang by saying that it might have started as if everything was once confined to a point from where it all originated, this states that there may not really be a centre. Also due to the expansion of universe I think one can not be sure of where this center may be now, had there been one originally

Comment: @rijul gupta [:](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/26063/rijul-gupta) I am more interested with the big bang model of the universe (more intuitive to me and also has wider acceptance) and that does indeed have a starting point . So I'll focus on that. Thank you though.

Comment: http://www.popsci.com/technology/article/2012-04/fyi-where-center-universe  , http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/GR/centre.html mostly everything scientific on net denies the universe having a centre

Comment: @RavindraHV: *I am more interested with the big bang model of the universe ... and that does indeed have a starting point .* You have this backwards. Big bang models do *not* have a center.

Comment: @rijul gupta [:](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/26063/rijul-gupta) Thank you for the links.I thought big bang was about 'explosion-in' space rather than 'expansion-of' space. I also found [this](http://spaceplace.nasa.gov/review/dr-marc-space/center-of-universe.html). However, I still like to think of a universe with a center. Since the universe has constant mass and energy (law of conservation of energy) can we not consider the center of gravity of the universe as its center, independent of the 'expansion'? This would hold true from the start of big bang, the present and the future.

Comment: How do you propose to find the centre of gravity ?

Comment: @BenCrowell [:](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/4552/ben-crowell) Thanks for pointing it out. I am still looking for a good excuse to say the universe has a center. [See my above comment](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82413/big-bang-and-spherical-symmetry/82415#comment171798_82413)

Comment: @rijulgupta I can not think of one. From my understanding, observations (so far) indicate that all objects (galactic scales) are moving away from each other at an equal pace (than away from a particular point). Since there has to be a center of gravity, we can look for inconsistencies in the expansion, see if any are found and then use that to guess. Absence of inconsistencies may not necessarily imply that it is so through out the universe. Its always possible we are not looking in the right place or may be we cannot simply hope to find out from our point of observation. I'll go with that.

Comment: It is not moving away (expanding) at a constant rate, the universe expands with different speed for different distances which I believe forbids us to find out its center

Comment: @rijulgupta According to this [link](http://www.universetoday.com/13810/why-are-distant-galaxies-moving-away-faster/), it is. Interestingly, that link uses the 'explosion-in' space perception of the big bang. In any case, I am more interested in whether or not the universe can be considered to have a center, which it looks like it can, in spite of the ongoing expansion and including the fact that it did not necessarily begin from a single point.

Comment: That wouod be a speculation, and those are unwelcome here

Comment: Which part are you referring to as speculation? The universe having a center? If yes, like I mentioned above I'd consider the center of gravity of the universe as the center. That's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The universe **is** spherically symmetric on the large scale - though it would be more precise to describe it as [isotropic and homogeneous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_principle). You can choose any point in the universe and you'll find it is approximately spherically symmetric about that point

Obviously it isn't perfectly spherically symmetric on scales less that [supercluster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercluster) dimensions. Our current best explanation for this is that at the end of [inflation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_inflation) quantum fluctuations introduced random variations in the universe density. These produced the inhomogeneities we currently see in the [cosmic microwave background](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background), and some millions of years later the first stars and galaxies.

Comment: Just extending the question, is it proven to be spherically symmetric ? Please post some links to established work on the subject

Comment: @rijulgupta: the measurements of the cosmic microwave background are the definitive measurement. They show that at the time of recombination the deviations from anisotropy were less than or equal to 1 part in 100,000. Although it's a long and hard business we can measure the current galaxy distributions and we find that on the large scale gaalxies are distributed evenly. See the Sloan Sky Survey (http://www.sdss.org/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for explaining but since we can observe the universe only for a limited distance, is it a good decorum to assert that we do have spherical symmetry ? The results may extrapolate to the unobservable part of universe, but they just as well may not, right ?

Comment: @John Rennie Is there any explanation to why the fluctuations were random? What 'broke' the symmetry to allow for (seemingly) random events?

Comment: @RavindraHV: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primordial_fluctuations for a good starting point on learning about the fluctuations. They were random because quantum fluctuations are inherently random.

Comment: @John Rennie [:](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1325/john-rennie) Thank you. Will do that. It looks like it'll be a while before I understand it.

Answer (score -1):

Very few nuclear reactions are symmetrical. Objects spin and often,  such as the planets and stars, have different equatorial and polar measurements. Pulsars emit energy in beams. Super Novae radiate out material in less than perfect symmetry.A  galaxy tends to spin in a non-symmetrical way. It would therefore be more likely in the "Big Bang" for the result to be anything but symmetrical

Comment: Please do elaborate.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. All the forces of nature conserve angular momentum, so they preserve spherical symmetry.

Comment: @paul You're perspective is to start from the current state and try to retrace how it might have begun. I am trying to guess how it may have been at the very beginning and wondering how it is that we have come to be. As per me it should have been ideally be a homogeneous spherically symmetric force. Also, what triggered the event itself will likely never be answered (If we go by newton's third law and the big-bang was a 'reaction' then what was the 'action' that caused it? Big-bang as the action itself does not make sense after all..).